# Flake8 - line break before binary operator - how to fix it?

Tags: python, flake8

I keep getting:

```
W503 line break before binary operator
```

Please help me fix my code, as I can't figure out what is wrong here:

```
def check_actionable(self, user_name, op, changes_table):
        return any(user_name in row.inner_text() and row.query_selector(
            self.OPS[op]) is not
                   None and row.query_selector(self.DISABLED) is not None for
                   row in changes_table)
```

Comment: You might wanna simplify that function into more than a one-liner. I's pretty unreadable. The flake8 warning is just a symptom of that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the other (imo better) alternative to `ignore` (which resets the default ignore list) is to use `extend-ignore`

by default both `W503` and `W504` are ignored (as they conflict and have flip-flopped historically).  there are other rules which are ignored by default as well that you may want to preserve

```
extend-ignore = ABC123
```

`ignore` on the other hand *resets* the ignore list removing the defaults

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer

Comment: thx for your additional information. I don't know you can set `extend-ignore` field in `.flake8` before.

Comment: This helped me realize that the reason I started getting `W503` and `W504` was because I added an ignore for a different error, which reset the default ignore list.

Answer (score 5):

W503 rule and W504 rule of flake8 are conflicted to each other. I recommend you to add one of them into your `.flake8`'s ignore list.

> W503: line break before binary operator

> W504: line break after binary operator

```
ignore = D400,D300,D205,D200,D105,D100,D101,D103,D107,W503,E712
```

The below code is prettified:

```
def check_actionable(self, user_name, op, changes_table):
    return any(user_name in row.inner_text() and
               row.query_selector(self.OPS[op]) is not None and
               row.query_selector(self.DISABLED) is not None for row in changes_table)
```

Some explanation on W503 and W504:

> binary operator: +, -, /, and, or, ...

To pass W503, your code should be like this:

```
x = (1
     + 2)
```

To pass W504, your code should be like this:

```
x = (1 +
     2)
```